# ChromeDriver default download directory not working in ChromeDriver v89,90

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I had been using below code to set default download directory in chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

The code was working fine with chromedriver-2.38, but when I tried to use the same code with ChromeDriver-v89 & v90, the download directory is not setting to workspace directory, instead it is downloading files to C:\Users<username>\Downloads.
I have tried many options but not able to identify what's wrong in the code

Selenium-server version 3.5.3 
Chromedriver-2.38 works fine 
Chromedriver-89.0.4389.23 - doesn't work 
Chromedriver-90.0.4430.24 - doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a `maven` (modeled by a `pom.xml` file) or `gradle` (modeled by a `build.gradle` file), you can add the [bonigarcia webdrivermanager dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` respectively to automatically import the binary executables and add their class paths to the project at runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively, you can use [Leonium](https://github.com/Git-Leon/leonium) , an uber-jar of `Selenium` & `WebDriverManger`, by adding the below repository & dependency to your `pom.xml`.

```
<!-- git-leon maven repository -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>git-leon-utils</id>
        <url>https://packagecloud.io/git-leon/utils/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!--selenium wrapper-->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.git-leon</groupId>
        <artifactId>leonium</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

By adding `Leonium` as a dependency you can fetch instances of a respective `WebDriver` by leveraging the [`BrowserHandlerFactory`](https://github.com/Git-Leon/leonium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/git_leon/leonium/browsertools/factories/BrowserHandlerFactory.java)

```
WebDriver firefoxWebDriver = BrowserHandlerFactory.FIREFOX.getDriver();
WebDriver chromeWebDriver = BrowserHandlerFactory.CHROME.getDriver();
WebDriver htmlunitWebdriver = BrowserHandlerFactory.HTMLUNIT.getDriver();
WebDriver phantomjsWebDriver = BrowserHandlerFactory.PHANTOMJS.getDriver();
```

You can also fork the [demonstration repository](https://github.com/Git-Leon/leonium-demonstration/) or even fork the [library's source code directly](https://github.com/Git-Leon/leonium). They are both accessible on github.

Comment: looking at your code it seems more like a Factory class which will provide instances of different types, it may have the other ways to manipulate browser parameters, but I am more keen into knowing what's wrong with the code mentioned in the question i.e. with Native Selenium code for ChromeDriver. Thanks